Notification channel with "banners" style
I have a device with Android 10 and OS modded probably by Huawei. I need full screen intents and heads up notifications working, but without "Banners" checked all my notifications are just common, flat usual ones (not popping on lock screen or below status bar when device unlocked). These features works fine on same Android version, but not modded, almost vanilla. And all tested devices (dozens), with newer or older OS versions (but must admit that no Huawei in that group..)
I'm looking for way for creating Notifiction channel which would have checked both "Banners" and "Lock screen" at start, I've tested few apps (just by installing and running once) and most of them got it...
This question is similar to THIS one, without marked/working answer...
And my notification settings screen for single channel looks a bit different:


Well, I've got official confirmation from producer (related to Huawei) that there is a whitelist hardcoded in this old OS version and fastest way to achieve "banners checked" is adding my package there using system/patch update - I've got few in last weeks, so devs are still working on some imprvs for this unit. So I'm waiting, meanwhile, sadly, this is the answer: common developer have no influece on this...
